# stop force save on a file with read only permission

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, chmod

I have a script file that is currently in `sudoers`, and for security I want this file to be read only... so I issued the following chmod:

```
chmod 555 test.sh
```

Now the permissions on this file are

```
-r-xr-xr-x
```

However, when I go to vi this file, even though it says `W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file`, I can still do "w!" to force save it. How can I also disable force saving so that a regular user wont be able to write to this file at all?

Comment: Force saving effectively deletes and recreates the file. The user needs write permissions on the parent directory to force save.

Comment: *So I have a script file that is currently in sudoers* What exactly do you mean by that?  If you just want users to be able to read the file, I can't see why you'd need `sudo` for that.  And if you don't want users to be able to modify the file, you likely don't want to enable `sudo` editing of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux systems, set the immutable file attribute with [chattr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html).

```
sudo chattr +i file
```

> A file with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file, most of the file's metadata can not be modified, and the file can not be opened in write mode.  Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

Use `lsattr` to list a file's attributes.

```
lsattr -l myfile
myfile    Immutable
```

The downside of doing this is that you won't be able to write to the file even as the superuser (root). You will need to remove the immutable attribute first:

```
sudo chattr -i file
```

On macOS, the [chflags](https://ss64.com/osx/chflags.html) command is used to set and reset the immutable flag. To set:

```
chflags uchg file
```

and to unset, or clear:

```
chflags nouchg file
```

These operations may be performed by either the owner of a file or the superuser.

With macOS, using the `-Ol` flags with `ls` show the immutable flag as `uchg` when set.